Remove spaces between quotes
I would like to remove the unnecessary space given after the opening quote and before the closing quote. I have huge data with this kind of text in Notepad++
Sample Text
The is the start of a paragraph:
" There is unnecessary "

There is unnecessary space given after and before the quotes which needs to be removed. Yet another sentence with the quotes:
" space before and after "

This is not looking good.
I have tried this so far, however, it seems I am in the wrong direction.
Here is the code (?<=")\s and \s(?=").

Multiple deductions and not a single comment.  For shame.


Ctrl+H
Find what: "\h*([^"]+?)\h*"
Replace with: "$1"
TICK Wrap around
SELECT Regular expression
Replace all

Explanation:
"               # double quote
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
([^"]+?)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but double quote, not greedy
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
"               # double quote

Screenshot (before):

Screenshot (after):


To replace the starting, quote space
Find \"\s Replace "

To replace the ending space quote
Find \s\" Replace "

If you wish to do everything in one replace
Find \"\s(.*)\s\" Replace "\1"


This is not working. It is removing the required space after the quotes.

This will change " xxx " to "xxx".  What else are you asking for?  Please edit the main post.    Give an example of what you want, before and after.  You have only given one example and this answer will give you the result for that example.  I don't understand the this is not looking good part of your question.
